# XAML Panels for WP8 Development

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to find a list of available panels in XAML for WP8 development. The reason I ask is because `FlowPanel`, `WrapPanel` and `UniformGrid` do not seem to be available.

Where can I find a list of available panels?

Comment: WrapPanel is included in the Silverlight Toolkit: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/94435

Comment: I installed Windows Toolkit which solved the problem.